# Db2 on Cloud: Problem with column in querying from R

Tags: r, db2, ibm-cloud

1. I created a connection between R and Db2 on Cloud

```
library(RODBC)
dsn_driver <- "{IBM DB2 ODBC Driver}"
dsn_database <- "bludb"            # e.g. "bludb"
dsn_hostname <- "**" 
dsn_port <- "***"   # e.g. "32733" 
dsn_protocol <- "TCPIP"            # i.e. "TCPIP"
dsn_uid <- "**"        #
dsn_pwd <- "**"      #
dsn_security <- "ssl"
conn_path <- paste("DRIVER=",dsn_driver,
                  ";DATABASE=",dsn_database,
                  ";HOSTNAME=",dsn_hostname,
                  ";PORT=",dsn_port,
                  ";PROTOCOL=",dsn_protocol,
                  ";UID=",dsn_uid,
                  ";PWD=",dsn_pwd,
                  ";SECURITY=",dsn_security,        
                    sep="")
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(conn_path)
conn
```

2. Then I created the table

```
myschema <- "**" #
tables <- c("Annual_Crop")
    
    for (table in tables){  
      # Drop School table if it already exists
      out <- sqlTables(conn, tableType = "TABLE", schema = myschema, tableName =table)
      if (nrow(out)>0) {
        err <- sqlDrop (conn, paste(myschema,".",table,sep=""), errors=FALSE)  
        if (err==-1){
          cat("An error has occurred.\n")
          err.msg <- odbcGetErrMsg(conn)
          for (error in err.msg) {
            cat(error,"\n")
          }
        } else {
          cat ("Table: ",  myschema,".",table," was dropped\n")
        }
      } else {
          cat ("Table: ",  myschema,".",table," does not exist\n")
      }
    }
df1 <- sqlQuery (conn, "CREATE TABLE Annual_Crop(
                    CD_ID char (6) NOT NULL,
                    YEAR CHAR (20),
                    CROP_TYPE varchar (50),
                    GEO varchar (50),
                    SEEDED_AREA CHAR (50) ,
                    HARVESTED_AREA CHAR (50),
                    PRODUCTION CHAR (50),
                    AVG_YIELD CHAR (50),
                    PRIMARY KEY (CD_ID))",
                    errors = FALSE)
if(df1 == -1){
    cat ("An error has occured.\n")
    msg <- odbcGetErrMsg(conn)
    print (msg)
    } else {
    cat ("Table was createdd successfuly.\n")
}
```

3. I loaded the dataset from a file into the table

```
anual_cropdf <- read.csv("/resources/labs/MYDATA/data1.csv")
sqlSave(conn, anual_cropdf, 'Annual_Crop', append=TRUE, fast=FALSE, rownames=FALSE, colnames=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)
```

[image]

4. Then I tried to fetch from the table and it works

```
FARMDB <- sqlFetch(conn, "Annual_Crop")
tail(FARMDB)
```

[image]

5. Finally, when I want to perform a query, it was not working. The result was just the name of columns 0X8

```
info <- paste('select * from Annual_Crop
           where Geo = 41600')
query <- sqlQuery(conn,info,believeNRows = FALSE)
query
```

[image]
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table schema, the data type for **Geo** is VARCHAR. Have you tried a query like this?

```
select * from Annual_Crop where Geo = 'Alberta'
```

or

```
select * from Annual_Crop where Geo = '41600'
```

Varchar / string needs to use single quotes for the value.